# How to pass Combining characters for custom keyboard layout in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, keyboard-layout

I was creating my custom keyboard layout(custom tamil keyboard layout) in Ubuntu 12.04 platform based on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10286878) post. I edited the file **/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in** as specified in the post with my custom layout. The sample layout mapping is attached below:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "tam_font_test" {
// Description: Tamil Custom Font KeyMap
// Encoding: Unicode (http://www.unicode.org)
// Author: Test

name[Group1]= "Tamil (Font Map - Test)";

// Qrow
key <AD02> {  [ U0BB1 ] };
key <AD03> {  [ U0BA8 ] };
key <AD04> {  [ U0B9A ] };
key <AD05> {  [ U0BB5 ] };
key <AD06> {  [ U0BB2 ] };
key <AD07> {  [ U0BB0 ] };
key <AD08> {  [ U0BC8 ] };
key <AD10> {  [ U0BBF ] };
};
```

I was successful with the above layout mapping.

However I have a typical requirement which i wasnt able to do it. I would like to map  the key AD03 with the following map

```
key <AD03> {  [ U0BA8, U0BA8+U0B8A ] };
```

where the second argument is the combining character such as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).
The syntax for the definition can be found in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto:%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) link.
The unicode character for tamil character can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf).

How can we pass the combining characters unicode as an argument to the mapping?

Comment: No time to write an answer right now, but [this link](http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a quote:

The line key  { [ quoteleft, asciitilde ] }; describes a single mapping from a key code ( in this case) to a group of symbols (` and in this case). Symbols are named, using the symbolic names from the /usr/X11R6/include/X11/keysymdef.h file, as described in section 2.4. A pair of symbols enclosed in brackets indicates a pair of symbols separated by a shift level; pressing the Shift key usually shifts between two levels, but the types component can override this. If a single symbol is enclosed in brackets, then this symbol is used always, independent of the level.

maybe a link is of some use: http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/node5.html

Comment: I think what the OP wanted is a way to type _two_ characters (together, one after the other) with a single key stroke (or key combination, e.g. with a shift key).